# Cambiar de pantalla sin usar el context en flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

Estoy creando una pequeña aplicación para ver como funciona las push notificación y ya casi tengo todo terminado solo que esto teniendo el problema de que no cambia de pantalla cuando se le da tap a la notificación mientras que la aplicación este abierta. Estoy usando un Gloabal y en la función que tengo que se ejecuta cuando le da tap a la función hago un inspect de Gloabal y esta regresa un null.
Lo que estoy intentando ahorita es declara la Globalkey en mi class NotificacionService y en MyApp mando a llamar navigatorKey y le paso la global key de la clase NotificacionService.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final pushProvider = new PushNotificationProvider();
    pushProvider.initNotifiactions();
    pushProvider.mensajes.listen((mensaje) {
      NotificacionService().showNotificacion(mensaje);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: NotificacionService().navigatorKey,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => PushNotificacion(),
        '/mensaje': (context) => MensajePage(),
      },
    );
  }
```

```
class NotificacionService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _fln =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  Future<void> init() async {
    final AndroidInitializationSettings initSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('caccesos');

    final InitializationSettings initSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initSettingsAndroid, iOS: null, macOS: null);

    await _fln.initialize(initSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotificacion);
  }

  Future selectNotificacion(String? payload) async {
    log('message');
    inspect(navigatorKey.currentState);
    navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('/mensaje');
  }

  void showNotificacion(Map<String, dynamic> payload) async =>
      await _notificacion(PushNotificationModel.fromJson(payload));

  Future<void> _notificacion(PushNotificationModel payload) async {
    const androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'id',
      'name',
      'description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: true,
      ticker: 'test ticker',
      showProgress: true,
    );
    const platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await _fln.show(0, payload.subtitle, payload.body, platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'test');
  }
}
```